# Can I pass a SC_HANDLE between processes?

Tags: winapi, windows-services, handle

The Windows API includes a useful function called [`DuplicateHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx), which can be used to transfer HANDLEs (to files, registry keys, processes, mutexes, etc.) from one process to another. This is useful for a number of things, including when writing sandboxes where sometimes a broker process will open a HANDLE (that the sandboxed process can't access) and then pass that HANDLE down to the sandbox. This is similar to passing file descriptors between POSIX processes via Unix domain sockets.

Unfortunately, the documentation for `DuplicateHandle` doesn't mention service handles (type `SC_HANDLE`, used/returned by APIs like [`OpenSCManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323(v=vs.85).aspx)) as a supported HANDLE type. Is there a way to duplicate (or otherwise transfer) those between processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These handles cannot be duplicated. The other process would need to call `OpenSCManager`.

Comment: Damn. Thank you. I'm leaving this open for a little while in case anybody comes up with a clever/obscure way of doing it, but I'll mark it as answered if nothing comes up in that time. I guess I can set the ACL on the SCM (and the relevant service) such that the sandbox can open it (without letting any other untrusted process open it... gah, I hate opening stuff to the sandbox directly), but I may just stick with my first plan (having the broker do all of the calls, in response to IPC from the sandbox). That means more IPC code and a perf hit, though. Damn.